# Determining voltage of fuse

Tags: voltage, charger, amperage, fuses

My car battery is dead, and the fuse in my car battery charger is missing....(don't ask me why)

I have a 20A fuse lying around and a 7.5A fuse that I took out of the car. The car battery charger states that it needs a 5A 32V fuse, so I'm guessing the 7.5A will be fine as a once off.  Is it?  My main question is, how do I determine the voltage of the fuse, since it's not written anywhere?

Any help will be GREATLY appreciated, as I can't exactly pick up my girlfriend from the bus station on my bicycle ha ha :)

Comment: "I can't exactly pick up my girlfriend from the bus station on my bicycle" Well, OTOH it's much more romantic (or at least you could put it that way :-)

Comment: That must be world's wimpiest charger with a 5A fuse- mine goes to 225A for starting and st like 40A continuous. Since you've probably got an extremely dodgy battery anyway, I suggest buying another (they come charged), pop it in, and use the car to pick up your gf and then a proper fuse. Some chargers have a 12V outlet and that might be fused at 5A, and replacing that fuse (which is easy to blow due to the difference between plugs) will not get you any closer to your goals.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I assume the OP is referring to a mains-powered charger which can't be used for starting.  Even so I'd say a 10A fuse for an ~8A output was more common (universal in the modern ones I've seen).

Comment: Your car fuse box will likely have "spare" or "unused" fuses that you could pull and use in the meantime (if there is a spare in the right value). Otherwise you can use (temporarily) the correct fuse from a non-vital or accessory circuit. If you are confident that the charger and battery are functional you could probably get away with a higher rated fuse if you don't leave it charging unattended and replace with the correct fuse as soon as you are moving

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have a 20A fuse lying around and a 7.5A fuse that I took out the car.

It probably is an ATO type fuse similar to this?

[image]

> The car battery charger states that it needs a 5A 32V fuse,

In general a replacement fuse should at least

- have a voltage rating equal or higher to the specified voltage
- have a current rating equal to or slightly smaller than the specified current

> so I'm guessing the 7.5A will be fine as a once off?

7.5A may not properly protect equipment from damage when 5A is specified, but it will probably OK for the charger.

The common ATO Automotive Blade Fuses are normally rated for 32V. The voltage rating matters with respect to arcing.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need worry about the fuse's voltage !
Typical car fuses can all handle the 12V present in a car.
So that is why many (car) fuses don't mention the voltage.

You can temporarily use the 7.5A fuse to replace the 5A one, it will work but
note that this will not give you the same protection as a 5A fuse. For example, 6A could flow, overload the charger but the fuse will not blow.
So it's at your own risk !